# How to append a variable to a drag & drop event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop

I'm writing a chrome extension and I have to transport with a drag&drop event two string variable from a page to another one. 
With jquery:

**Page source:**

```
     $('.myClass').on('drag', function(){
         //my function for append the 2 variable 
     });
```

**Page target:**

```
      $('.myClass').on('drop', function(){
         //my function for read the 2 variable 
     });
```

I don't know where I have to put the variables in the drag and how control if they exist in the drop.

Comment: you may create a global object and attach it to window. i.e., var myvar={};. then use window.myvar.va1 = "somevalue";window.myvar.va2 = "somevalue2"; then read it like window.myvar.va1

Comment: @user2536037 If the drag is done between two windows or tabs (as the OP says it is), the two pages will have different `window` objects.

Comment: How about appending the values to the dragged object itself?

Comment: @apsillers the drag is done by two windows or tabs. can I use the window object of the first in the second tab?